# Image popup function is working but unabel to see the image on pop-up

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, ionic-framework

1. 1.I was building a ionic Mobile App in that  i have a gallery and i was trying to view a image as pop-up from gallery, pop-up was
   working fine and it fetch the image path too but unable to see image
   on pop-up.

   **here my app.js**

   ```
   function galleryController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location,$ionicModal, profile){
   /*alert(0);*/
       profile.galleries(window.localStorage['token']).success(function(data){
           /*alert(JSON.stringify(data));*/
           if(data.status == 200)
           {
               $scope.gallery = data.data.gellary;
               //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
           }
           $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('partials/gallery.html', function(modal) {
               $scope.gridModal = modal;
               }, {
               scope: $scope,
               animation: 'slide-in-up'
           });
           // open video modal
           $scope.openModal = function(selected) {
               $scope.data = selected;
               $scope.gridModal.show();
           };
           // close video modal
           $scope.closeModal = function() {
           $scope.gridModal.hide();
       };
       //Cleanup the video modal when we're done with it!
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.gridModal.remove();
       });
       });          
   };
   kangaroo.directive('gridImage', function(){
       alert("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
       return function($scope, element, attrs){
       var url = attrs.gridImage;
       element.css({
       'background-image': 'url(' + url +')',
       });
      };
   });
   ```
2. I was fetching image from s3 Amazon by using api , this is  html
   code in my gallery.html where i get the data from my controller i
   can see the image in gallery and not able to see on pop-up don't
   know what was the problem.

   ```
   **gallery.html page**


   <ion-header class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
       <!-- <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button> -->


   </ion-header>
   <div class="padding" >

   <div ng-controller="galleryController">
   <ion-content class="content has-header ionic-pseudo" style="margin-top:19px">
   <div ng-repeat="x in gallery" >
   <img ng-src="{{x.thumb_img}}" ng-click="openModal(x)" alt="" class="gallery_i" />
   </div>
   </ion-content>
             <script id="partials/gallery.html" type="text/ng-template">
               <div class="modal" ng-click="closeModal()">
                   <img ng-src="{{data.thumb_img}}" />          
               </div>
             </script>
   </div>
   </div>
   ```

**please help me out of this
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: that's not the way to post on stack overflow, you have to correctly indent you're code. This is to make easier to help you for people.

Comment: ya i got it  thanks @mautrok

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking

Comment: i am new to stack overflow but i kept the code which is required to my problem

Comment: i can't get what i was doing wrong in posting a question @evc

Comment: @dinnigandra What does it mean "I cannot see the image on pop-out"?

Comment: cant see the image on pop-up @Avalanche

Comment: Just when i click on the image the pop-up working just like fade in fade out but image was not loading on it @Avalanche

Comment: @dinnigandra Now it sounds like wrong paths to me, check if they are correct and accessible

Comment: No even i can see the path of the image which was clicked  in inspect elements @Avalanche